# Importing a custom library into a storybook

Tags: node.js, typescript, storybook

I am writing a TypeScript library. I have gotten to the point where I would like to test said library. Because it's a very visual thing, I chose to go with storybook so I can show off the different functionalities of my library.

My package has an `index.ts` with the following in it:

`export { Container } from "./Container";`

My folder structure looks like this:

```
library/
    dist/
    src/
        index.ts
        Container.ts
    package.json
    storybook/
        stories/
        package.json
```

This is the package.json of my library:

```
{
  "name": "@wesp/customcontainer",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
}
```

This is the dependencies for the package.json of the storybook folder:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@wesptest/customcontainer": "file: ../",
},
```

Now when I try to use the custom library in for example `storybook/stories/test.stories.ts`:

```
import {Container} from "@wesp/customcontainer";
```

but then the story will throw this error:

```
_wesp_customcontainer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Container is undefined
```

What do I have to change so I can successfully import this class?

thanks.

-- edit --

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declaration": true,
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`main` of your lib is `dist/index.js`.

Storybook file will try to import from dist dir, so first check if js file exists in that dir.

Comment: The file exists.

Comment: @wes.p Try including tsconfig too

Comment: I included the tsconfig

Comment: maybe webpack config too

Comment: the tutorial i follow did not say I need webpack, it only tell me to use `tsc --watch`